# How can I link to and object's parent in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have the following models:

```
    class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :pages, :dependent => :destroy
    end

    class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :section
    end
```

And I had a section owning a page, how could I add a link_to that would link to that pages parent? Or, how could I find a page's owner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@page      = Page.find(params[:id])  # or whatever the criteria
@page_link = link_to "section", @page.section
```

Or, in the view:

```
<%= link_to "section", @page.section %>
```